# Extended jquery popup positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for ready for use js or jquery code of positioning my popup block according to the following rules:

1. It appears near to user's cursor when he clicks on the text, better under the text line, but if it's not possible (at the bottom of page), then above.
2. It is centering to the user's cursor, but if user clicks near the right border of window it shifts to the left side.
3. Width of the popup is fixed, but height can be different, but not more then some maximum value.

Popup is just div with position:absolute attribute.

[example1](https://monosnap.com/image/FFMUIEVtmgTSQdpIyyPwigE6EijowU)
[example2](https://monosnap.com/image/lnLI5AvZ4Cf0rtyKEXncTrjL9ecPIf)

Comment: So, what have you tried? Do you have any code samples?

Comment: No, I'm bad js-programmer